# Hide textview if Prev Data is the same with the current in Listview

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a code below that display data in my custom listview

```
final List<Map<String, String>> data1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
while (data.moveToNext()) {
    Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(5);
    datum.put("Name", data.getString(0));
    datum.put("Remarks", data.getString(2));
    datum.put("Date", data.getString(3));
    datum.put("Others", data.getString(4));
    data1.add(datum);
}
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data1,
        R.layout.listview_plan,
        new String[]{"Name", "Remarks", "Date", "Others"},
        new int[]{R.id.list_name,
                R.id.list_remarks,
                R.id.list_date, R.id.list_others}){
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v  = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        return v;
    }
};

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have textview called `R.id.list_date` and it displays Date values and my data is order by date. My question is how can I hide `R.id.list_date` if the data from prev is same on the current

Comment: See this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)

Comment: thnx but i didnt find any solution on what you gave

Comment: can you store prev data

Comment: what do you mean storing?

Comment: If you have prev data then you can check with this data in list and hide textview

Comment: can you give me some codes on that because thats the one i cant do very sorry 1st time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data1,
            R.layout.listview_plan,
            new String[]{"Name", "Remarks", "Date", "Others"},
            new int[]{R.id.list_name,
                    R.id.list_remarks,
                    R.id.list_date, R.id.list_others}){

        String previousDate = "";

        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v  = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView tvDate = v.findViewById(R.id.list_date);
            String currentDate = ((Map<String, String>)getItem(position)).get("Date");
            if (currentDate != null){
                if (currentDate.equals(previousDate)) tvDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                else tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                previousDate = currentDate;
            }

            return v;
        }
    };
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try this

Comment: I have an error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null`

Comment: I fixed the error. I hope i can ask you another regarding to this one

Comment: Glad to see you have fixed the error. If you still have questions about ListView, my blog may help: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/